# Want to access Username in current HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, log4net, httpcontext

I want to access the Username of current Logged in User into Web.Config so that I can use it with Log4Net.
I have made a new file as::

```
namespace VZDev.Helpers
{


    class HttpContextUserPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
    {
        protected override void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            string name = "Temp Name";
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context != null && context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                name = context.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            writer.Write(name);
        }
    }

}
```

Here the Context sets to null value.
How can I get the username in above code??
-----------------------------`-----------------------
while I use`HttpContext` in my controller code as,

```
string temp = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

at that time I am getting the Username of logged in User.

Comment: Do you want to get value from context, when context is not available?

Comment: yes I want to get Value from context,
I want username from that

Comment: From where in your code are you accessing the "Convert" method? My guess is that you try to do it before the HttpContext is created.

Comment: Which part of the `if` statement is false?

Comment: @HenkMollema to my understanding, the "context" variable is null which in turn would make the if hit false on the first condition..

Comment: I see, but OP is also stating that `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` works. (I assume he means `HttpContext.Current.User` in stead of `HttpContext.User`)